# Python requests doesn't upload file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to reproduce this curl command with Python requests:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/gpx+xml' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary @test.gpx "http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/?app_id=my_id&app_key=my_key" -o output.json
```

The request with curl works fine. Now I try it with Python:

```
import requests

file =  {'test.gpx': open('test.gpx', 'rb')}

payload = {'app_id': 'my_id', 'app_key': 'my_key'}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/gpx+xml', 'Accept':'application/json'}


r = requests.post("https://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/", files=file, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

And I get the error:

```
<Response [400]>
{u'messages': [], u'error': u'Invalid GPX format'}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to specify `data-binary` somewhere?

The API is documented here: https://mapmatching.3scale.net/mmswag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curl uploads the file as the POST body itself, but you are asking `requests` to encode it to a multipart/form-data body. Don't use `files` here, pass in the file object as the `data` argument:

```
import requests

file = open('test.gpx', 'rb')

payload = {'app_id': 'my_id', 'app_key': 'my_key'}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/gpx+xml', 'Accept':'application/json'}

r = requests.post(
    "https://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/",
    data=file, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

If you use the file in a `with` statement it'll be closed for you after uploading:

```
payload = {'app_id': 'my_id', 'app_key': 'my_key'}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/gpx+xml', 'Accept':'application/json'}

with open('test.gpx', 'rb') as file:
    r = requests.post(
        "https://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/",
        data=file, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

From the [`curl` documentation for `--data-binary`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary):

> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.
>
> If you start the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a filename. Data is posted in a similar manner as `--data-ascii` does, except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and conversions are never done.