# Python requests return empty response after file upload

Tags: api, file, post, python-requests, upload

I want to upload a file via Python requests. I have successful tries with Postman and Curl. On successful response, I get the file id, but using requests i get status code 200 and empty json.

Curl example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://someurl.com/api/file' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic TWFsZWtzZXkubHVraW55a2hfdGVzdDE6UWF6MVdzeEA=' \
--form 'file=@"1.png"' \
--form 'fileName="1.png"' \
--form 'fileType="image/png"'
```

Curl output:

```
{
    "fileId": 328446
}
```

Python requests:

```
import requests


session = requests.session()
files = {'file': ('1.png', open('1.png', 'rb'), 'image/png',)}
response = session.post('http://someurl.com/api/file', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('my_login', 'my_password'), files=files)
print(response.json())
```

requests output:

```
{}
```

I also tried to attach a file through this topic, but the version of the requests is older there

[Python requests doesn't upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255533/python-requests-doesnt-upload-file)

Postman form-data example

[API POST request Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCtsu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. This code works

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url = 'http://someurl.com/api/file'
payload={'fileName': '1.png', 'fileType': 'image/png'}
files= {'file': open('1.png','rb')}
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('my_login', 'my_password'), data=payload, files=files)

print(response.json())
```